# How to refresh a datetime tag every second in a Django Template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4, refresh

I use Django 3 + Bootstrap 4 + MySQL 5.7 on a Laragon server, all on Windows 10.

I have a view with a variable `dt_now = timezone.now()` displayed in a Template with a simple `<p>{{ dt_now }}</p>` tag.
I want to refresh this tag every second automatically without reloading all the htlm page.
Is there a simple way to do that with Django or Bootstrap ?
Or maybe should I prefer to use a jQuery methode  ?
At last, should I write a custom function ?

Comment: an ajax request to the server in every seconds instead of raising value in javascript is not an effective way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS without any framework:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = currentTime;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="currentTime"><p>
```